# Policy based network management - operation modes

Tags: snmp, nms

Can someone explain to me what PBNM operation modes(i.e, initialization, provisioning and outsourcing) are? If not can anyone give me a reference to some textbook etc.Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Lots of people like to make up terminology. Can you provide a quote or link to where this term is used?

Comment: It's a network management system. ( PBNM- policy based network management.)
https://slideplayer.com/slide/8379063/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a term that the author of the [slide deck](https://slideplayer.com/slide/8379063/) invented.  He explains the concepts in the presentation.  There is no generally accepted definition of these terms. The author seems to borrow many concepts from the AAA framework.